# Not allowed: no-auth-role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: geo:ListGeofences on resource: xxxxx

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm trying to use some of the new Amazon Location Service endpoints from the SDK itself (Location) and I have run into some inconsistent errors.

Even with everything allowed in the IAM Role `geo:*` (same for every resource), I always find errors of not authorization for functions like `locationClient.listGeofences`.

Arbitrarily, some other functions like `getMapStyleDescriptor`, `searchPlaceIndexForText` or `calculateRoute` do not give problems. Those functions are using their respective policies within `geo:...`, so it's pretty confusing to me to see how it detects some policies and others not.

The error is pretty common, it shows the following and the policy it's already allowed:

```
Uncaught (in promise) AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/AmazonLocationTestRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: geo:ListGeofences on resource: arn:aws:geo:eu-west-1:xxxx:*
```

Note that the acess is for unauthenticated users withing an indentity pool in Cognito, but that shouldn't be the problem.

```
                const client = new AWS.Location({
                    credentials: credentials,
                    region: AWS.config.region
                });

                console.log(await client.listGeofences({
                    CollectionName: "explore.geofence-collection"
                }).promise())

                console.log(await client.getMapStyleDescriptor({
                    MapName: mapName
                }).promise());
```

Just in case, the trust relationships in the IAM role look like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-west-1:xxxx"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "unauthenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And every policy for every resource in Amazon Location Service it's already allowed.

Do you have any idea what could be happening?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/authenticating-using-cognito.html#cognito-create-user-pool unauthenticated identities have access only to the following operations:

1. geo:GetMap*
2. geo:SearchPlaceIndex*
3. geo:BatchUpdateDevicePosition
4. geo:CalculateRoute